# What to do after exposure to a drive-by infection?

Tags: malware, web-browser, virus, drive-by-download

I clicked on a link that pretty clearly offered exposure to a drive-by infection.

I won't post the link itself, but I got it from a link which is inside a reddit link (obviously the reddit website itself is fine, it's the link that someone posted on reddit that is the problem).

I realised straight away there might be a problem and closed the browser. What can I do?

Comment: Why do you think there was a drive-by infection? They typically require a browser bug. Much more common is a page that pretends to infect you and then tries to trick you into doing something bad such as paying money or downloading an infection.

Comment: I wouldn't think real drive-by infections would have a reason to announce themselves. Usually websites claiming infection are phishing to get you to do something you shouldn't.

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to identify known malware and exploit fragments with a malware scan. This might address your concerns quickly and easy.

But if it was a more professional attack this might not be possible. If you assume your computer is compromised you might have to re-format the device and re-install the operating system. This action would be mandatory in high-security environments.